# bootable DVD & USB of Centos 6.5 x86 based from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, usb, software-center, system-installation, dvd

My question is how to make a bootable DVD / USB for CentOS 6.5 x86(32-bit) from Ubuntu 13.10 (with the help of terminal / GUI or through both ways) OR what softwares i can use for this purpose???

In addition to this extent, I m interested to know what type of DVD/CD have a property or ability, that i can easily write data on it and after completion  of work, I can delete the data written and write something else for other uses of DVD? If so then please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brasero can burn images to a disk as can K3b (which I prefer for multi-session projects). CDRW and DVDRW disks can be erased and re-used. A flash drive would be less hassle and faster in the long run.